# route hijacking/Cannot bind source type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel to model type

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, content-management-system, umbraco

I am trying to make a strongly typed view in umbraco..but I am stuck at a point where I am getting this error.

> Cannot bind source type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel to model type
>   umbraco_demo.Model.HomeModel.

My model class:

```
public class HomeModel : RenderModel
{
    //Standard Model Pass Through
    public HomeModel(IPublishedContent content) : base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent, UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.Culture) { }

    //Custom properties here...
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    public ActionResult HomeModel(RenderModel model)
    {
        //we will create a custom model
        var myCustomModel = new HomeModel(model.Content);
        myCustomModel.MyProperty1 = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        //TODO: assign some values to the custom model...

        return CurrentTemplate(myCustomModel);
    }
}
```

View in umbraco:

```
@using umbraco_demo.Model
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<HomeModel>
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
@{Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("MyProperty1");}
```

Also I have a document type in umbraco with name Home having above template.

I even referred this [post on umbraco forum](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/75998-update-to-742-all-custom-hijacked-controllers-stopped-working) 
But still getting same error.

Comment: In your controller, replace `return CurrentTemplate(myCustomModel);` with `return View(myCustomModel);`

Comment: still the same error "Cannot bind source type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel to model type umbraco_demo.Model.HomeModel."

Comment: Try removing `@using umbraco_demo.Model` from your view - you don't need it.

Comment: Now getting another error 'The type or namespace name 'HomeModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)' line--->public class _Page_Views_Home_cshtml : UmbracoViewPage<HomeModel> {

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you running?

Comment: Umbraco version 7.5.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fixing the controller

Change your controller method name to:

```
public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

The `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController` has a method also called `Index` which you need to override. It will probably otherwise use that virtual method as the default (which will return a different model type).

`Index` is also the default method will be called when a page is loaded with no (GET or POST) params.

If you used a debugger on your controller, you should have been able to see your custom method was not being hit on page load.

### Updating the model

I haven't used your specific implementation of the model. It may be worth changing the constructor to:

```
public HomeModel(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture) : base (content, culture) { }
```

And changing the instantiation in the controller of this model to:

```
var myCustomModel = new HomeModel(model.Content, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

### View changes

The line in your view where you're trying to get the property `MyProperty1` is probably wrong. I assume that this property does not exist on your Umbraco Node, but you mean to access the property on your custom model.

Change:

```
@{Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("MyProperty1");}
```

To:

```
@{var myProperty1 = Model.MyProperty1;}
```

Comment: upvotted as explained well...though didnt solve the problem.

Comment: I have added some further fixes for some potential issues.

Comment: after implementing view changes suggested by you..i had my project working finally.BTW @Model.MyProperty1 also gives same result.

Comment: Interesting, I guess the constructor didn't work..? Might be worth submitting an issue with Umbraco HQ.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that your controller name is the same as the document type that you are currently working with